# Python Incrementing

Tags: python, nltk, addition, subtraction, sentiment-analysis

I am writing a program that will accept text as an input.

The program has a value "tone" that starts at 0.
Tone increments by +1 when it sees a word in that text that is also in a list of words "posfeats." 
Tone increments by -1 when it sees a word in that text that is also in a list of words "negfeats."

However, my code is returning a 0 for the value "tone" no matter what input text I give it. I feel that this is due to my faulty Python programming rather than my algorithm.

Here is the code:

```
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews #importing two corpora, movie_reviews and stopwords
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def word_feats(words):
stops = dict([(word, True) for word in stopwords.words('english')]) #English stopwords
features = dict([(word, True) for word in words if word not in stops])#features minus stopwords
return features

def compare(words, negfeats, posfeats):
sentiment=0
for word in words:
    if word in negfeats:
        sentiment -= 1
    if word in posfeats:
        sentiment += 1
return sentiment


negReviews = reviews.fileids('neg')
posReviews = reviews.fileids('pos')

negfeats = [(word_feats(reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in negReviews]
posfeats = [(word_feats(reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'pos') for f in posReviews]

opinion = raw_input("Why don't you tell me about a movie you watched recently?\n\n")
tone = compare(opinion.split(), negfeats, posfeats)
print(str(tone)) #THIS KEEPS RETURNING 0
```

Comment: Why did you add "tone=0" as the first line in compare()? I'm unsure how it affects the return value, but I don't think it should be there, instead it should be `sentiment=0`!

Comment: If you want an unordered collection of elements without duplicates, it's cleaner to use a `set` instead of a `dict` with ignored values.

Comment: @Kohler, you're right, I completely wrote that wrong when I was copying it over to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
negfeats = [(word_feats(reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in negReviews]
posfeats = [(word_feats(reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'pos') for f in posReviews]
```

Did you mean to have `dict` calls here? `negfeats` and `posfeats` are lists of `(word, 'neg')` and `(word, 'pos')` tuples. `compare` will search these lists for words and not find any, because the words are nested in the tuples. Of course, it'd be better to use `set`s for unordered collections without duplicates.

Comment: For some reason, I typed it wrong while copying it over to stackoverflow. My code does say sentiment=0 now. But I'm still getting a value of 0...

Comment: @user3180238: Don't retype it, then. Copy/paste is so much easier and more reliable.

Comment: @user3180238: Updated answer to reflect the new version of your code.